# How to open an XML file with python client for google cloud storage

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

Im a total noob and have no other way of solving this so I need to do it with Python. I need to parse an xml-file. This works fine when the file is stored locally. But, I need to be able to open the file in Google Cloud Storage.

Please see my code. I dont know how to pass the blob as a filename to ElementTree. If I use blob.download_as_string() I get the content of the xml file as the name. Which ofcourse is too long and wrong path to the file.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from google.cloud import storage
client = storage.Client()

#My bucket
bucket = client.get_bucket('import')

# This is my file
blob = bucket.get_blob('/xml/Profit.xml')

xml_file = blob.download_as_string()
#xml_file is now looooong string and not what I want

root = ET.parse(xml_file)
#This doesnt work...

result = ''

for elem in root.findall('.//LEVEL1/DATA'):
    mystr = elem.text.replace(" ","").replace("+","").replace("-","")
    print mystr.replace(" ","").replace("+","").replace("-","")
```

I expect the xml_file variable to containt the path to the file in my bucket. Or find a way to parse the content of the file.

Any suggestions that point me in the right directions are appreciated.

Cheers,
Cris

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the file and parse it:

```
import cloudstorage as gcs
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

# The filename argument is specified in the format of YOUR_BUCKET_NAME/PATH_IN_GCS
gcs_file = gcs.open(filename)
contents = gcs_file.read()
gcs_file.close()

root = ET.fromstring(contents)
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me. I get this error: module 'cloudstorage' has no attribute 'open'. I installed the package.

Comment: See https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/googlecloudstorageclient/read-write-to-cloud-storage#top_of_page

Comment: ok I need to enable appengine to  access the file? I thought it would be enough to install this package https://github.com/scottwernervt/cloudstorage/

Comment: Thanks! ok any suggestions on how to use the downloaded blob when parsing?

Comment: I got it to work nice now. I used my initial code with the "ET.fromstring(contents)" that you suggested and now I can parse the string.

Comment: If your issue is solved you can vote up for the answer.